# How to show zip file content and load document in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, zip

I have a requirement to download zip file and show the files in zip and opening any file it will load the document.
Is there any library or how to meet this requirement?

Answer (score 2):

you can use `unzipit` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/unzipit)
it's pretty simple to use, you can scan all the files in the ZIP and then you can do whatever you want. i.E. if it'a an image you can display it as HTML